# how to fill a column in a csv file using C++ without modifying its existent content?

Tags: c++, csv, ofstream

I need to write a program in C++ to fill a column of a csv file. However my program delete the existing content of the csv file.
Is there a way to write to a csv file without modifying the other cells?

Comment: more code is required

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Read in the complete file, change data, overwrite old version of file.

Option 2: Seek correct position, overwrite data point if the number of chars is equal. If they are not equal move the rest of the file.

The basic problem with files is that they are just a array of bytes, basically. If you want to replace something in the middle, with something that has not the same amount of bytes, you have to move the rest, so that the data is consecutive. Long story short, there is no magically function here.

Comment: For example, what do I need to modify in my following program?#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>  
using namespace std;
void f();
int main()
{ 
f();
cin.get();
 
return 0;
}

void f(){
 ofstream outdata("C:\\file.csv");
for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
  outdata << rand() << endl;
 
}

Comment: what should the program do?

Comment: It should fill the first column in "file.csv" with random numbers but without modifying the other data in the csv file

Comment: you can only append to a file. adding data anywhere else requires to move the existing data back, so far that there is space for the data to insert.